# Subtracting rows in loop using key in R

Tags: r

I have data frame in which i have to subtract the ib in row 13 - row 1, row 14- row 2 respectively. Till row 12 for each key i have to keep as it is value.
You can use the data in R

```
zz <- "S_No key ib  new_ib
1   3A19Bangladesh  5215    5215
2   3A19Bangladesh  10543   10543
3   3A19Bangladesh  14346   14346
4   3A19Bangladesh  17642   17642
5   3A19Bangladesh  20423   20423
6   3A19Bangladesh  22838   22838
7   3A19Bangladesh  25400   25400
8   3A19Bangladesh  25880   25880
9   3A19Bangladesh  29400   29400
10  3A19Bangladesh  32000   32000
11  3A19Bangladesh  32960   32960
12  3A19Bangladesh  32960   32960
13  3A19Bangladesh  32960   27745
14  3A19Bangladesh  32960   22417
15  3A19Bangladesh  32960   18614
1   3A19Belarus 364 364
2   3A19Belarus 1140    1140
3   3A19Belarus 2085    2085
4   3A19Belarus 3100    3100
5   3A19Belarus 4007    4007
6   3A19Belarus 5331    5331
7   3A19Belarus 7078    7078
8   3A19Belarus 7078    7078
9   3A19Belarus 7878    7878
10  3A19Belarus 8878    8878
11  3A19Belarus 9378    9378
12  3A19Belarus 9378    9378
13  3A19Belarus 9378    9014
14  3A19Belarus 9378    8238
15  3A19Belarus 9378    7293"
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: All you seem to be asking for is `Data[13, "ib"] - Data[1, "ib"]`? In a loop this would be (eg) `for (i in 13:nrow(Data)) { Data[i, "tmp"] <- Data[i, "ib"] - Data[i - 12, "ib"] }`

Comment: Thanks @aocall your solution helped us to some extent.